# i am a beginner in Rstudio !! my doublt is regarding = installing devtools

Tags: rstudio

library(devtools)
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘bitops’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘devtools’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
install.packages("bitops")
```